# Positive number which has no prime factor greater than k

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, c++14

I tried to create a function which takes two variables `n` and `k`.

The function returns the number of positive integers that have prime factors all less than or equal to `k`. The number of positive integers is limited by `n` which is the largest positive integer.

For example, if `k = 4` and `n = 10`; the positive integers which have all prime factors less than or equal to 4 are 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12...(1 is always part for some reason even though its not prime) but since `n` is 10, 12 and higher numbers are ignored.

So the function will return 7. The code I wrote works for smaller values of `n` while it just keeps on running for larger values.

How can I optimize this code? Should I start from scratch and come up with a better algorithm?

```
int generalisedHammingNumbers(int n, int k)
{
    vector<int>store;
    vector<int>each_prime = {};

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
        {
            if (i%j == 0 && is_prime(j))
            {
                each_prime.push_back(j);   //temporary vector of prime factors for each integer(i) 
            }
        }
        for (int m = 0; m<each_prime.size(); ++m)
        {
            while(each_prime[m] <= k && m<each_prime.size()-1)  //search for prime factor greater than k
            {
                ++m;
            }
            if (each_prime[m] > k);  //do nothing for prime factor greater than k
            else store.push_back(i);  //if no prime factor greater than k, i is valid, store i
        }
        each_prime = {};
    }

    return (store.size()+1);
}

bool is_prime(int x)
{
    vector<int>test;
    if (x != 1)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < x; ++i)
        {
            if (x%i == 0)test.push_back(i);
        }
        if (test.size() == 0)return true;
        else return false;

    }
    return false;

}


int main() 
{
    long n;
    int k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    long result = generalisedHammingNumbers(n, k);
    cout << result << endl;


}
```

Comment: Why isn't `3` in your results? Its prime factors are `3`, which is less than `4`.

Comment: @Barmar sorry that was a mistake. 3 is part of it.. i'll edit it

Comment: Anyway, to solve your problem you should run the program in a debugger or add print statements to see what it's doing.

Comment: @Barmar I don't know if you changed the return result on purpose (from 5 to 6).

Comment: @Armfoot I did, because he said `3` should be in the result list. You undid that change with your edit.

Comment: @Barmar  ahhh..i forgot to add 9 too...i'll edit it again..my bad..i'll also put the is_prime() function i created and the print statement

Comment: And if you don't want `1` to be included, either start your loop at `2` or change `is_prime()` so it returns `false` when the parameter is `1`.

Comment: @Barmar the issue with the code is that it takes forever to return answer for larger values of n. e.g 100000.

Comment: Your code has `O(n^3)` time complexity. The nested loops in `generalisedHammingNumbers` are `O(n^2)`, and `is_prime()` is `O(n)`. You need to redesign your algorithm. You can improve `is_prime()` by caching the results and also using Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: "1 is always part for some reason". It's included exactly by the definition, so I'd say that's a very good reason, not just "some reason". It's a positive integer, and every one of its prime factors is less than or equal to `k` (regardless of the vaue of `k`). (It has no prime factors, so that statement is what's often called "vacuously true", but that doesn't make it any less true.)

Comment: You might want to look at the [code for Hamming numbers](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hamming_numbers) for ideas about doing this efficiently. (Hamming numbers are the special case of your problem where `k=5`, but many of the algorithms should generalise nicely.)

Answer (score 1):

> Should I start from scratch and come up with a better algorithm?

Yes... I think so.

This seems to me a work for the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

So I propose to

1) create a `std::vector<bool>` to detect, through Eratosthenes, the primes to `n`

2) remove primes starting from `k+1`, and their multiples, from the pool of your numbers (another `std::vector<bool>`)

3) count the `true` remained values in the pool vector

The following is a full working example

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

std::size_t foo (std::size_t n, std::size_t k)
 {
   std::vector<bool> primes(n+1U, true);
   std::vector<bool> pool(n+1U, true);

   std::size_t const sqrtOfN = std::sqrt(n);

   // first remove the not primes from primes list (Sieve of Eratosthenes)
   for ( auto i = 2U ; i <= sqrtOfN ; ++i )
      if ( primes[i] )
         for ( auto j = i << 1 ; j <= n ; j += i )
            primes[j] = false;

   // then remove from pool primes, bigger than k, and multiples
   for ( auto i = k+1U ; i <= n ; ++i )
      if ( primes[i] )
         for ( auto j = i ; j <= n ; j += i )
            pool[j] = false;

   // last count the true value in pool (excluding the zero)
   return std::count(pool.begin()+1U, pool.end(), true);
 }

int main ()
 {
   std::cout << foo(10U, 4U) << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: @xskxzr - interesting... I'm not an expert of computational complexity but I'm curious: with "last log n for each operation on numbers" do you mean the cost of operations as `++i`, `j += i`? Another question: the time complexity of all operation is the same lon n or there is a difference between addition, multiplication and division?

Comment: @xskxzr - yes, obviously this is relevant only when `n` is very large. Anyway, when you say that my algorithm "has the highest asymptotic time complexity among the three answers", have you considered the time complexity for multiplications and divisions in other answers?

Comment: I researched and learned that when analyzing time complexity, we usually use the [RAM model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine), which seems to be able to perform any normal arithmetic operation on unbounded operands in constant time (one instruction) theoretically. Sorry for possible misleading... In this computation model, your algorithm has the highest time complexity. Of course, your algorithm has the advantage of avoiding multiplications and divisions, so I don't know which is the fastest in practice.

Comment: @xskxzr - your considerations are interesting reasoning over the algorithms; so the log n part for operations is relevant when n is so great that the numbers are represented using a variable number of bytes (some big-ints libraries do this); it's obvious that operations over base C++ types (POD) are constant time (are like manual operations over single digits numbers) but this doesn't change the asymptotically correctness of your considerations.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the primes using a sieve of Erastothenes, and then use a modified coin-change algorithm to find numbers which are products of only those primes. In fact, one can do both simultaneously like this (in Python, but is easily convertible to C++):

```
def limited_prime_factors(n, k):
    ps = [False] * (k+1)
    r = [True] * 2 + [False] * n
    for p in xrange(2, k+1):
        if ps[p]: continue
        for i in xrange(p, k+1, p):
            ps[i] = True
        for i in xrange(p, n+1, p):
            r[i] = r[i//p]
    return [i for i, b in enumerate(r) if b]

print limited_prime_factors(100, 3)
```

The output is:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 16, 18, 24, 27, 32, 36, 48, 54, 64, 72, 81, 96]
```

Here, each time we find a prime `p`, we strike out all multiples of `p` in the `ps` array (as a standard Sieve of Erastothenes), and then in the `r` array, mark all multiples of any number that's a multiple of `p` whether their prime factors are all less than or equal to `p`.

It runs in O(n) space and O(n log log k) time, assuming n>k.

A simpler O(n log k) solution tests if all the factors of a number are less than or equal to k:

```
def limited_prime_factors(n, k):
    r = [True] * 2 + [False] * n
    for p in xrange(2, k+1):
        for i in xrange(p, n+1, p):
            r[i] = r[i//p]
    return [i for i, b in enumerate(r) if b]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an Eulerian version in Python (seems about 1.5 times faster than Paul Hankin's). We generate only the numbers themselves by multiplying a list by each prime and its powers in turn.

```py
import time

start = time.time()

n = 1000000
k = 100

total = 1
a = [None for i in range(0, n+1)]
s = []
p = 1
while (p < k):
  p = p + 1

  if a[p] is None:
    #print("\n\nPrime: " + str(p))
    a[p] = True
    total = total + 1
    s.append(p)

    limit = n / p
    new_s = []

    for i in s:
      j = i
      while j <= limit:
        new_s.append(j)
        #print j*p
        a[j * p] = True
        total = total + 1
        j = j * p
    s = new_s

print("\n\nGilad's answer: " + str(total))
end = time.time()
print(end - start)

# Paul Hankin's solution
def limited_prime_factors(n, k):
    ps = [False] * (k+1)
    r = [True] * 2 + [False] * n
    for p in xrange(2, k+1):
        if ps[p]: continue
        for i in xrange(p, k+1, p):
            ps[i] = True
        for i in xrange(p, n+1, p):
            r[i] = r[i//p]
    return len([i for i, b in enumerate(r) if b]) - 1

start = time.time()
print "\nPaul's answer:" + str(limited_prime_factors(1000000, 100))
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```